# Setting background in the front of two divs with gradient

Tags: html, css, background, gradient

I defined two divs with an gradient:

```css
.container_middle_page{
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.container_middle_page_up{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #F28118,white);
    height: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.container_middle_page_down{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #F28118,white);
    height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_middle_page">
  <div class="container_middle_page_up">Div1</div>
  <div class="container_middle_page_down">Div2</div>
</div>
```

Now I wanna add a background image which is visible in the front of the two divs with gradient.
If I do something like:

```css
background-image: url("/path") no-repeat, linear-gradient(to bottom, #F28118,white);
```

I set the background only for one of the two divs. How can I set the background for both divs?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```css
.container_middle_page_up{
    background-image: url("/path"), linear-gradient(to top, #F28118,white);
    height: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.container_middle_page_down{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    background-image: url("/path"), linear-gradient(to bottom, #F28118,white);
    height: 50%;
}
```

I just had to add the image to both divs.